# How can I get the specific element in a json-like element in python?

Tags: python, json, xml, elementtree

I have an XML file containing some Open Street Map nodes. I am trying to select a node randomly. To do this first I am going to get the ids of all the nodes into an array and then select an id randomly. Then I wish to get the node which has that id number.

Now, I read the xml file and do the following:

```
tree = ET.parse('/Users/XXX/Documents/map.osm.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

idd = [] # ids of the nodes

for n in root.iter('node'):
    idd.append( n.attrib["id"] )
```

Each `n.attrib` in the loop is something like this :

```
{'id': '6676298011', 'visible': 'true', 'version': '1', 'changeset': '72944617', 'timestamp': '2019-08-02T14:49:11Z', 'user': 'bkrc', 'uid': '8150490', 'lat': '41.0836908', 'lon': '29.0511424'}
```

How can I get the one with the id, for example, 6677592585 ?

```
# whole code :


import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import random
import json

tree = ET.parse('/Users/XXX/Documents/map.osm.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

idd = []
for n in root.iter('node'):
    idd.append( n.attrib["id"] )

i = idd[0]

print(i)
```

Comment: `if '6677592585' == n.attrib["id"]:` then append it or fetch whatever you want to.

Comment: I have the list idd, ids of nodes. I completed the loop to have it. Then I am gonna get a random value from that list. Do you think I should make another loop to find it? I thought there was an easier way to do it.

Comment: I personally wouldn't loop again, it would not allow for scalability. But I don't know what you're planning for this code.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this isn't what you're looking for, but I would take advantage of the fact that you're already looping through all the nodes to get their id.

Assuming the `id` is unique for each node, while making a list of the ids I would create a new dict where the given id is a key to the node. So then when you randomly select your id you can just use it to get the node out of your new dict. This might not be a good solution if you have memory limitation, but the only other solution I can think of is looping through the original structure each time you want to get a node until you find the selected id in a given node, which would be CPU intensive. Maybe it would look something like this

```
idd = [] # ids of the nodes
mapped_nodes = {}

for n in root.iter('node'):
    idd.append( n.attrib["id"] )
    mapped_nodes[n.attrib["id"]] = n
```

If you just need `n.attrib` you could also just put that in your `mapped_nodes`